# In PHP - is there a way to know when fsockopen times out?

Tags: php, sockets

I was wondering if anyone knows a way to know when fsockopen times out? 
For instance if I set the timeout to 5 seconds, can I define a handler to do something if it hits that timeout connecting to my server?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [man page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php):

> If the value returned in errno  is 0 and the function returned
> FALSE, it is an indication that the
> error occurred before the connect()
> call. This is most likely due to a
> problem initializing the socket.